# Select a multiple-key cross section from a DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame "df" with (time,ticker) Multiindex and bid/ask/etc data columns:

```
                          tod    last     bid      ask      volume
    time        ticker                  
    2013-02-01  SPY       1600   149.70   150.14   150.17   1300
                SLV       1600   30.44    30.38    30.43    3892
                GLD       1600   161.20   161.19   161.21   3860
```

I would like to select a second-level (level=1) cross section using multiple keys. Right now, I can do it using one key, i.e.

```
    df.xs('SPY', level=1)
```

which gives me a timeseries of SPY. What is the best way to select a multi-key cross section, i.e. a combined cross-section of both SPY and GLD, something like:

```
    df.xs(['SPY', 'GLD'], level=1)
```

?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are better ways of doing this with more recent versions of Pandas (see [Multi-indexing using slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.14.0.html#multi-indexing-using-slicers) in the changelog for version `0.14`):

```
regression_df.loc[(slice(None), ['SPY', 'GLD']), :]
```

This can be made more readable with the use of [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```py
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ['SPY', 'GLD']], :]
```

With the convention `idx = pd.IndexSlice`, this becomes

```py
df.loc[idx[:, ['SPY', 'GLD']], :]
```

Comment: Note that this also works if you have a multi index as column ;)

Comment: A potentially big inconvenience of this is you can't specify `level="ticker"` like you can with `DataFrame.xs`

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't find a more direct way other than using `select`:

```
>>> df

       last   tod
A SPY     1  1600
  SLV     2  1600
  GLD     3  1600

>>> df.select(lambda x: x[1] in ['SPY','GLD'])

       last   tod
A SPY     1  1600
  GLD     3  1600
```

Since Pandas version 0.21.0, the `select` has been [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select.html). The same effect can be achieved with

```py
df.loc[df.index.map(lambda x: x[1] in ['SPY','GLD'])]
```

Comment: Nice, this is probably the simplest way. I wonder if it is the most efficient though, as calling lambda for each row might be slow, but then again I'm not sure if there's a faster way in the current version

Comment: did u see panel solution above? select if very inefficient for any kind of non-trivial frame

Answer (score 5):

For what it is worth, I did the following:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12,3), 
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B','C','D'],['Green','Red','Blue']], 
                                                    names=['Letter','Color']),
                   columns=['X','Y','Z']).sort_index()

foo.reset_index()\
   .loc[foo.reset_index().Color.isin({'Green','Red'})]\
   .set_index(foo.index.names)
```

This approach is similar to select, but avoids iterating over all rows with a lambda.

However, I compared this to the Panel approach, and it appears the Panel solution is faster (2.91 ms for index/loc vs 1.48 ms for to_panel/to_frame:

```
foo.to_panel()[:,:,['Green','Red']].to_frame()
```

Times:

```
In [56]:
%%timeit
foo.reset_index().loc[foo.reset_index().Color.isin({'Green','Red'})].set_index(foo.index.names)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.91 ms per loop

In [57]:
%%timeit
foo2 = foo.reset_index()
foo2.loc[foo2.Color.eq('Green') | foo2.Color.eq('Red')].set_index(foo.index.names)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.85 ms per loop

In [58]:
%%timeit
foo2 = foo.reset_index()
foo2.loc[foo2.Color.ne('Blue')].set_index(foo.index.names)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.37 ms per loop

In [54]:
%%timeit
foo.to_panel()[:,:,['Green','Red']].to_frame()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 ms per loop
```

**UPDATE**

After revisiting this topic (again), I observed the following:

```
In [100]:
%%timeit
foo2 = pd.DataFrame({k: foo.loc[k] for k in foo.index if k[1] in ['Green','Red']}).transpose()
foo2.index.names = foo.index.names
foo2.columns.names = foo2.columns.names
100 loops, best of 3: 1.97 ms per loop

In [101]:
%%timeit
foo2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: foo.loc[k] for k in foo.index if k[1] in ['Green','Red']}, orient='index')
foo2.index.names = foo.index.names
foo2.columns.names = foo2.columns.names
100 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop
```

If you don't care about preserving the original order and naming of the levels, you can use:

```
%%timeit
pd.concat({key: foo.xs(key, axis=0, level=1) for key in ['Green','Red']}, axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 ms per loop
```

And if you are just selecting on the first level:

```
%%timeit
pd.concat({key: foo.loc[key] for key in ['A','B']}, axis=0, names=foo.index.names)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 ms per loop
```

versus:

```
%%timeit
foo.to_panel()[:,['A','B'],:].to_frame()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 ms per loop
```

**Another Update**

If you sort the index of the example `foo`, many of the times above improve (times have been updated to reflect a pre-sorted index). However, when the index is sorted, you can use the solution described by user674155:

```
%%timeit
foo.loc[(slice(None), ['Blue','Red']),:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 582 µs per loop
```

This is the most efficient and intuitive in my opinion (the user doesn't need to understand panels and how they are created from frames).

Note: even if the index has not yet been sorted, sorting the index of `foo` on the fly is comparable in performance to the `to_panel` option.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to a panel, then indexing is direct

```
In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(time = pd.Timestamp('20130102'), 
                                A = np.random.rand(3), 
                 ticker=['SPY','SLV','GLD'])).set_index(['time','ticker'])

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
                          A
time       ticker          
2013-01-02 SPY     0.347209
           SLV     0.034832
           GLD     0.280951

In [22]: p = df.to_panel()

In [23]: p
Out[23]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 1 (items) x 1 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
Items axis: A to A
Major_axis axis: 2013-01-02 00:00:00 to 2013-01-02 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: GLD to SPY

In [24]: p.ix[:,:,['SPY','GLD']]
Out[24]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 1 (items) x 1 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: A to A
Major_axis axis: 2013-01-02 00:00:00 to 2013-01-02 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: SPY to GLD
```

Comment: Panel will explode sparse structures. .loc slice answer is more general

Comment: Note: panels have been deprecated since Pandas version 0.20.0 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Panel.html

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to refer to the MultiIndex level by number, then MultiIndex slicing (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36243537/10778387)) is a simple (but not necessarily optimal) solution.

However, you might wish to refer to the MultiIndex level by name rather than number. This may be useful where tracking the MultiIndex level by number is hard to read (because you have many levels) or unreliable (because the number and order of levels might change during data processing).

This can be done by combining Boolean indexing with `get_level_values`.

```py
df.loc[map(lambda x: x in ['SPY','GLD'], df.index.get_level_values('ticker'))]
```

`df.index.get_level_values` returns the Index at just the "ticker" level.
`map` then iterates over the Index, making an iterable of True and False values.
`df.loc` can take a Boolean iterable and return just the rows for which the iterable is True.

If you want to drop the "ticker" level from your MultiIndex (which `xs` does by default), you can add the extra line

```py
df.index = df.index.droplevel("ticker")
```

On a dataframe I've been using (42 rows, 49 columns, 4 level MultiIndex), I found Boolean indexing to be twice as fast as slicing when asking for two indices: `df.loc[(slice(None), ['SPY','GLD']), :]`, or about N times faster when asking for N indices.
If you wish to index by number but still use Boolean indexing, `get_level_values` also accepts a numeric argument (in your case, `1`).