# The right way to select multiple cross-sections on a DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have a MultiIndex DataFrame on which I am selecting interesting cross-sections.  The code works, but is slow on large datasets which makes me think I'm doing something wrong.  Essentially I have been concatenating multiple cross-sections into a new DataFrame, and I am looking for a better way.

### The dataset

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

# setup dataset
event = ['event0', 'event1', 'event2']
node = ['n0', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3']
config = ['a', 'b']
data = []
for x in itertools.product(*[event, node, config]):
    data.append([x[0], x[1], x[2], np.random.randn()])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['event', 'node', 'config', 'value'])
dfi = df.set_index(['event', 'node'])
print dfi.head(n=12)
```

which looks like:

```py
            config     value
event  node
event0 n0        a  1.256259
       n0        b  0.612465
       n1        a  1.593518
       n1        b -0.747131
       n2        a  0.719973
       n2        b  1.063480
       n3        a -0.943120
       n3        b  2.021804
event1 n0        a -1.427104
       n0        b -0.440886
       n1        a  0.168212
       n1        b -1.084987
```

### Some Analysis

I do some analysis which gives me a list of indexes that I care about:

```py
# Find interesting (event,node) 
g = df.groupby(['event', 'node'])['value']
gmin = g.min()
idxs = gmin[(gmin<-1.2)].index
print idxs
#idxs = [(u'event1', u'n0'), (u'event1', u'n2'), (u'event2', u'n0')]
```

### And the clumsy cross-sections

Now I just care about the interesting event, node combinations.  This is the part which is slow on real data sets.  Each `.xs` might take 100ms, but they add up:

```py
df2 = pd.concat([dfi.xs(idx) for idx in idxs]) 
print df2
```

Which gives the value for every configuration of the interesting (event, node) cross section:

```py
            config     value
event  node
event1 n0        a -1.427104
       n0        b -0.440886
       n2        a  0.273871
       n2        b -1.224801
event2 n0        a -1.297496
       n0        b -1.087568
```

### References

- A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463729/select-multiple-key-cross-section-from-a-dataframe/15478827#15478827) recommends a Panel.  I have not been able to figure out the right indexes to make this work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll be much better off using [groupby's `filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) method *(new in 0.12!)*, which was designed for exactly this purpose:

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby(['event', 'node'])

In [12]: g.filter(lambda x: x['value'].min() < -1.2)
Out[12]: 
     event node config     value
0   event0   n0      a -1.566442
1   event0   n0      b -1.652915
14  event1   n3      a  1.685070
15  event1   n3      b -3.205499
20  event2   n2      a -3.007079
21  event2   n2      b  0.159409
```

*(My numbers are different, as they were generated randomly!)*

You can then [set the index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to event and node to get your desired result:

```
In [13]: g.filter(lambda x: x['value'].min() < - 1.2).set_index(['event', 'node'])
Out[13]: 
            config     value
event  node                 
event0 n0        a -1.566442
       n0        b -1.652915
event1 n3        a  1.685070
       n3        b -3.205499
event2 n2        a -3.007079
       n2        b  0.159409
```

Comment: nice example for the cookbook!

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick.  The ``.filter`` method seems to take the same time regardless of the number of records which meet the selection criteria unlike the ``.xs`` concat method.  I suppose this is obvious, but I thought I would mention it.

Comment: @chip Thanks for mentioning that, interesting. It was written with speed in mind (and to avoid hacky workarounds): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3680 :)