# Multiple-key cross-sections in Pandas. Dealing with misses and duplicate indices

Tags: python, pandas

There seem to be three different ways of doing multiple-key cross-sections in Pandas:

- [Using pd.IndexSlice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258781/advanced-cross-section-with-multi-index-in-pandas)
- [Using groupby's filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389576/the-right-way-to-select-multiple-cross-sections-on-a-dataframe?lq=1)
- [Converting to panel, getting the cross-section, and converting back again to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463729/select-multiple-key-cross-section-from-a-dataframe)

However, I am unable to run the solutions described in those threads. Let me explain:

## Example that works with `idx`:

Say I want to get the cross-section `['bar', 'flux']` associated with `A` from the following series:

```
> my_series
       
A    B                           
bar  one    0.269566  
     three  1.156823 
flux six    0.087296 
     three -2.652280 
foo  five   0.216790 
     one   -0.652412 
     two    0.590229 
     two   -1.570565
```

If I do:

```
> idx = pd.IndexSlice
> my_series.to_frame().loc[idx[['bar', 'flux'],:], :]
```

I get:

```
A    B                           
bar  one    0.269566  
     three  1.156823 
flux six    0.087296 
     three -2.652280
```

which is correct (it gives me the cross-section for `['bar', 'flux']`.

### Example that fails (keys not present) with `idx`:

Now, say that I include a key in the list of cross-section keys that does **not** exist (e.g. `does_not_exist`), I get:

```
> my_series.to_frame().loc[idx[['bar', 'does_not_exist'],:], :]

KeyError: 'does_not_exist'
```

But what if I did **not** know a priori that `does_not_exist` was not present in level `A`? How can I avoid the error and still get whatever matches from the requested cross-section? How can I properly pre-prune the keys to make sure that the cross-section works with any keys matching?

Also, in the example above, do I need to go through a frame to use `idx`? If I try to use it directly I get:

```
> idx = pd.IndexSlice
> my_series[idx[['bar', 'something_else'],:], :]
TypeError:
```

why?

### Example that fails (duplicate indices) when [using the "panel" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463729/select-multiple-key-cross-section-from-a-dataframe):

If, instead, I try `my_series.to_frame().to_panel().ix[:,my_keys, :]` I get:

```
ValueError: Can't convert non-uniquely index DataFrame to Panel
```

but I thought I could use the *"convert to panel"* solution described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15478827/283296) to get the cross-section. Why does it fail?

### Addendum:

To create the random series I included as an example at the top of the post, I used:

```
def create_random_multi_index():
  df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                            'foo', 'flux', 'foo', 'flux'],  
                     'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                            'two', 'six', 'five', 'three'],
                     'C' : randn(8), 'D' : randn(8), 'E': randint(0,3, size=(8,))})
  df.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
  df.sort_index(inplace=True)
  return df
```

and then I did (for example):

```
my_series = create_random_multi_index['C']
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
s = Series(np.arange(9),index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B','C'],['foo','bar','baz']],names=['one','two'])).sortlevel()
```

Comment: You need to give an example that is copy-pastable. show the construction of the frame, the operation, and what you expect/want.

Comment: @user815423426 I don't think your dataframe is copy-pastable, at least when I tried with `read_clipboard()`. Are you constructing it manually from code with something like `numpy.random.randn()`? If so, probably best to provide that code so people can actually play with your example data.

Comment: don't use ``to_frame()`` nor ``Panels``. What exactly are you trying to do? e.g. show a frame that constructs your input and a frame that constructs the output. Try using ``MultiIndex.from_product`` or ``MultiIndex.from_tuples`` from the documentation

Comment: @Jeff I apologize for making the original post unnecessarily complex. I hope my question is clearer now. Please let me know otherwise.

Comment: Thank you @Marius. I added an `Addendum` at the end of the post that shows how to create the Series I included as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be a API issue, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7866. This could and should work I think.

Create sample data. In general make sure it is lexsorted.

```
In [17]: s = Series(np.arange(9),index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B','C'],['foo','bar','baz']],names=['one','two'])).sortlevel()

In [21]: s
Out[21]: 
one  two
A    bar    1
     baz    2
     foo    0
B    bar    4
     baz    5
     foo    3
C    bar    7
     baz    8
     foo    6
dtype: int64
```

Regular selection. If the values are not found a `KeyError` will be raised.

```
In [18]: s.loc[idx[:,'foo']]
Out[18]: 
one
A      0
B      3
C      6
dtype: int64
```

To select with a mask. Here the mask is a boolean array whether the values exist.

```
In [19]: s.loc[idx[:,s.index.get_level_values('two').isin(['foo','bah'])]]
Out[19]: 
one  two
A    foo    0
B    foo    3
C    foo    6
dtype: int64
```

Might be easier to simply reindex.

```
In [20]: s.reindex(['foo','bah'],level='two')
Out[20]: 
one  two
A    foo    0
B    foo    3
C    foo    6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting that the first `s.loc` you wrote returns a single-index series, while the second `s.loc` call and the `reindex` call return a two-index series. Is that the way it is supposed to work? Can I do it in a way that *always* returns results with the original multi-index structure?

Comment: sure, you just need to specify a list rather than a scalar indexer, e.g. ``s.loc[idx[:,['foo']]]``