# Simple pandas MultiIndex slicing

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
df_1 = DataFrame({
        "alpha" : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3] ,
        "beta" : [3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5] ,
        "val_1" : ["x", "y" , "z", "w", "a", "b", "v1" , "v2" , "v3" ] ,
        "val_2" : ["z1", "z2" , "z3", "w1", "w2", "w3" , "zz1" , "zz2" , "zz3" ]
    })
df_1.set_index(["alpha", "beta"], inplace=True)
```

I am trying to select the following highlighted rows:

[image]

That is, every row where `beta` is either 3 or 5.

I have gone through the pandas documentation multiple times and cannot find a way to do this. The closest I've come to what I think must be the answer is:

```
df_1.xs((3,5), level="beta", drop_level=False)
```

Which now currently fails.  What is the proper indexing/slicing way to get this?

Comment: couldn't you just brute force it? or it the dataset to large?

Comment: In this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463729/select-a-multiple-key-cross-section-from-a-dataframe they solve basically the same problem by converting it to a `Panel`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`DF.query()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method to subset based on the specified values:

```
df_1.query('beta == 3 or beta == 5')  # More succintly : df_1.query('beta == [3,5]')
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty awesome.  I have avoided `query()` till now because it has been marked "experimental" but honestly, this seems so much more intuitive than the indexing methods.  Is there any reason not to use `query()` all the time (i.e. performance, etc.)?

Comment: AFAIK, `.query()` can be efficient when you have a large sized `DF` (maybe of the order of a million rows) when compared to the normal boolean indexing logic. Also, currently it lacks various string handling capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `get_level_values` and `isin` to construct a logical series for indexing:

```
df_1[df_1.index.get_level_values(1).isin([3,5])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.IndexSlice`. There is a [very similar example](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) directly in the documentation.

```
df_1.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, [3,5]], :]


           val_1 val_2
alpha beta            
1     3        x    z1
      5        z    z3
2     3        w    w1
      5        b    w3
3     3       v1   zz1
      5       v3   zz3
```

Comment: For the record a variation of this answer: `df.loc[(slice(None), [3,5]),:]`