# Pandas Multiindex dataframe remove rows

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have Multiiindex DF as follows:

```
tuples = list(zip(*[['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'c', 'd']]))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['i1', 'i2'])
df = pd.DataFrame([5, 6, 7, 8], index=index[:4], columns=['col'])

       col
i1 i2     
a  c     5
   d     6
b  c     7
   d     8
```

Would like to keep rows whose index (level 0) is in

```
idx_to_keep = ['a']
```

Should be a straightforward task, but I can't think of any other way than

```
idx_to_drop = np.setdiff1d(pd.unique(df.index.levels[0]), idx_to_keep)
df.drop(idx_to_drop, inplace = True)

       col
i1 i2     
a  c     5
   d     6
```

Can I do better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select a multiple-key cross section from a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463729/select-a-multiple-key-cross-section-from-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use the `index` method `get_level_values()`:

```
df
       col
i1 i2     
a  c     5
   d     6
b  c     7
   d     8

df[df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(idx_to_keep)]
       col
i1 i2     
a  c     5
   d     6
```

Comment: Found a cleaner solution, using 'level' parameter: 
    df = df[df.index.isin(idx_to_keep, level=0)]

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `loc`:

```
df.loc[['a']]
```

The resulting output:

```
       col
i1 i2     
a  c     5
   d     6
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [.xs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df.xs('a', axis=0, level=0, drop_level=False)
```

Which gives:

```
       col
i1 i2     
a  c     5
   d     6
```

Comment: Also if looking to preserve index level 0, can specify `drop_level=False`

Comment: what if I want to keep more than just 'a'  (keep both 'a' and 'b' for example).