# Dropping list of rows from multi-level pandas dataframe without a loop

Tags: python, pandas

Cannot figure out how to drop a list of multi-level rows from a pandas dataframe with greater than 3 levels, without resorting to a for loop.

This works fine when explicitly defining all values in the index as answered by:
[Pandas Multiindex dataframe remove rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333949/pandas-multiindex-dataframe-remove-rows)

e.g.

```
mask = dfmi.index.isin(( ('A0','B0', 'C0'), ('A2','B3', 'C4') ))
dfmi.loc[~mask,:]
```

However when one wants to accept all possible third level:

```
dfmi.index.isin(( ('A0','B0', slice(None)), ('A2','B3', slice(None)) ))
```

The result TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Currently I am achieving this with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def mklbl(prefix, n):
     return ["%s%s" % (prefix, i) for i in range(n)]

miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A', 4),
                                   mklbl('B', 4),
                                   mklbl('C', 10)])

dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(miindex) * 2)
               .reshape((len(miindex), 2)),
                index=miindex).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

As = ['A0', 'A2']
Bs = ['B1', 'B3']

for a,b in zip(As, Bs):
    dfmi_drop_idx = dfmi.loc[(a, b, slice(None)), :].index
    dfmi.drop(dfmi_drop_idx, inplace=True, errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Are you looking to drop all rows with these particular index values, or just the rows corresponding to `(A0, B1, :)` and `(A2, B3, :)`? Because that's a bit unclear from your question.

Comment: I am looking to drop only the unique combination of rows (A0, B1, :) and (A2, B3, :). Obviously my full list of row combinations is very large, hence the need to avoid a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the `MultiIndex` index then drop it

```
dfmi.drop(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([As,Bs]))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `drop` on a list of tuples should do the trick

```
dfmi.drop([*zip(As, Bs)])
```

To verify, this is a modified version of your code.  We'll compare outputs to asser equality.

```
from functools import reduce
didx = reduce(
    pd.MultiIndex.union,
    [dfmi.loc[pd.IndexSlice[a, b, :], :].index
     for a, b in zip(As, Bs)]
)

assert dfmi.drop(didx).equals(dfmi.drop([*zip(As, Bs)]))
```

Comment: I might've misinterpreted the question.