# Why can't pandas.xs select multiple keys from one level?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe with a ~10 levels multiindex and timeseries data, like this:

```
country     Elbonia       ... Elbonia        ...
state       Upper Elbonia ... Lower Elbnonia ...
city        Krschmsh      ... Chkchk         ...
elevation   1400          ... 800            ...
...
importance  high          ... mid            ...
visit       yes           ... maybe          ...
Date
1930-01-01  Nan           ... 500            ...
1930-02-01  358,2         ... 501            ...
```

and I can select things very straightforward and readable with `.xs`, like `Chkchk = Elbonia.xs('Chkchk', level='city', axis=1, drop_level=False)` and have one new, smaller dataframe. So far, so good. If I need more than one city, I could grab the whole state of Upper Elbonia with `Elbonia.xs('Upper Elbonia', level='state'...` or all the cities with a `high` importance and so on.

But let's say I need a dataframe that contains both, `Krschmsh` in Upper Elbonia and `Chkchk` in Lower Elbonia.
The [xs documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#cross-section) says "xs also allows selection with multiple keys", but apparently, the *multiple* **MUST** be applied to both, the key and the level. The obvious `Elbonia.xs(('Krschmsh', 'Chkchk'), level='city', axis=1, drop_level=False)` fails with a `KeyError`.

Now I'm not the first to notice this, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463729/select-a-multiple-key-cross-section-from-a-dataframe) are a bunch of solutions for simple dataframes, but those don't work for me*.

**So what is the reason that `.xs` can't do this seemingly very simple and obvious selection of two keys from one level?**

*I'm just selecting each city as one dataframe, and then concat them together. The solutions linked above are probably *better* but for this code it is very important that is says *what* is selected and from *which level* of the large multiindex, for which I have only found only `.xs` as an easy and straightforward solution.